# Check in text with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have link:

```
<a href="/test/number/3/phone/0">33df</a>
```

How can i check if in this link are words 'number' and 'phone'?

I would like function for example:

```
   check('number', '<a href="/test/number/3/phone/0">33df</a>'); //return TRUE
   check('phone', '<a href="/test/number/3/phone/0">33df</a>'); //return TRUE
   check('mail', '<a href="/test/number/3/phone/0">33df</a>'); //return FALSE
```

i would like use jQuery

Comment: There are a number of jQuery validation plugins available for download.  You could also take a regx approach but I would suggest finding a validation plugin you can sink your teeth into.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function will check all of your `<a>` tags and return a list of `<a>` elements if they contain the text. **[Check out this jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/PfX8R/2/)**

```
function check(text, elements){
    var list = [];
    if(!elements)
        $('a').each(function(){
            if($(this).attr('href').indexOf(text)!=-1)
                list.push(this);
        });
    else
        $.each(elements,function(){
            if($(this).attr('href').indexOf(text)!=-1)
                list.push(this);
        });
    return list;
}
console.log(check('number'));
```

If you wanted to test and make sure that you are returning `<a>` elements that contain multiple words, you could then do something like this:

```
matches = check('number');
matches = check('phone', matches);
matches = check('mail', matches);
console.log(matches);
```

Answer (score 2):

No need for jQuery just use `indexOf()`

[jsFiddle EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/S3HhS/)

```
function check(token, value){
   return value.indexOf(token) >= 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   var href = $("a").attr("href");
    if(href.indexOf("number") >= 0){
     alert("contains number");   
    }
    if(href.indexOf("phone") >= 0){
     alert("contains phone");   
    }
    if(href.indexOf("mail") >= 0){
     alert("contains mail");   
    }
```

See Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CcLHz/

Answer (score 0):

```
function check(text, str) {
    var r = new RegExp(text, 'gi');
    return r.test(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, and I've even granted your request to use jQuery:

```
var check = function(val, linkHtml) {
    return ($(linkHtml).attr("href").indexOf(val) >= 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function check(word, str) {
    var p = new RegExp(word);
    return str.match(p);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RegExpObject.test(string)
```

In your case it would be:

```
if(/(phone)+|(number)+/.test('<a href="/test/number/3/phone/0">33df</a>'))
{
//returns true
}else{
//returns false
}
```

This should work. Cheers.